# How to draw Views on Canvas

Tags: android

I want to load e.g. LinearLayout with some Buttons from xml and draw it on Canvas in a way that the Views behave normally (I can set onClick actions for the Buttons *and when I press a Button, it changes it's background drawable*). Can I do this?

Comment: yes you can (i hope you get the point...)

Comment: I think so, but just to be sure... what is the point?

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your View in a Bitmap and create a Canvas based on your Bitmap like [here](http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/30676.aspx).

Comment: I tried something similar (I just simply called View.draw() method), but when user clicks on the Button, I send the motion event to the root view, but the Button doesn't change it's background drawable.